# How to allow hidden custom fields to be added from wp-admin/post.php?

Tags: posts, post-meta

I know that using an underscore in front of a custom field name hides it from display on the front-end, e.g. `_custom_field_name`. In my experience, WordPress also prevents one from adding such a custom field on the front end.

Before I go spelunking around core, I wanted to ask: Is there an "easy" way to allow `_custom_fields` to be added from wp-admin/post.php?

The reason is this: we rely on hidden custom fields, but when troubleshooting production issues in prod it would be useful to be able to inject certain hidden post meta. I'm not a fan of touching the production database by hand.

[image: what i get]

Comment: Post your code, please. For what is worth, I don't recall ever having trouble inserting keys with leading underscores.

Comment: Where are you wanting to inject hidden custom fields? On the Editor page or when the post is displayed to the user?

Comment: Post my code? There is none relevant to the question. If I'm wrong, my apologies. Re-testing now.

@CharlesClarkston exactly, via `wp-admin/post.php?post={$ID}&action=edit`

Comment: @s_ha_dum updated to show what I see when trying to add a custom field.

Comment: What do you mean by *front end*? Because it doesn't really seem relevant to this question. The *front end* is the *template*, as output by the browser. In that context, post meta data are all the same.

Comment: Also, I don't really understand your question. Prefixing a post meta key with an underscore will hide that meta key from the **custom fields** UI. The purpose is that such post meta keys would be configured via a **custom post meta box**. If you're adding post custom meta keys via the *custom fields* UI, then you would have no need to hide those post meta keys from the custom field UI, and would thus have no reason to prefix the meta key with an underscore. So, what are you really after? Just an easy way to see all defined post meta?

Comment: Front-end, you know - client side. Want to be able to add "protected" post meta while working from the post edit interface. I'm good now, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the [following filter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/meta.php#L870), here unlocking all protected meta data:

```
add_filter( 'is_protected_meta', '__return_false' );
```

Or it can be fine tuned:

```
add_filter( 'is_protected_meta', function( $protected, $meta_key, $meta_type )
{
    $allowed = array( '_edit_lock', '_test', '_wp_page_template' );
    if( in_array( $meta_key, $allowed ) )
        return false;

    return $protected;
}, 10, 3 );
```

It allows to display the meta data as well as insert new ones (globally or fine-tuned).

Answer (score 1):

Custom fields that begin with an underscore are hidden from the editor. This is so other methods can access them, but they will not show up as "custom fields". For example, this is how most Custom Fields plugins work.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta#Hidden_Custom_Fields

If you wish to bypass this, you should be able to:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-show-hidden-custom-fields-in-wordpress/

Comment: "I know that using an underscore in front of a custom field name hides it from display on the front-end."

Sorry, I tried to cover this but must not have been clear enough in my question: What I'm looking for is the ability to leave them hidden for display while allowing them to be added from the "add new" Custom Fields interface.

Comment: @editor - You should have added this clarification to the Question, I answered without this info... Anyway, I think you cannot have both. . . . GhostToast - that CSS trick ain't working on my side, but even if it did I think it wouldn't suffice.